# How do I store and load a list of key-value pairs in a string?

Tags: string, delphi, tstringlist

I have a list of strings and the values they are to be replaced with. I'm trying to combine them in a list like `'O'='0',' .'='.', ...` so it's easy for me to edit it and add more pairs of replacements to make.

Right now the best way I could think of it is:

```
var
  ListaLimpeza : TStringList;
begin
  ListaLimpeza := TStringList.Create;

  ListaLimpeza.Delimiter := '|';
  ListaLimpeza.QuoteChar := '"';
  ListaLimpeza.DelimitedText := 'O=0 | " .=."';

  ShowMessage('1o Valor = '+ListaLimpeza.Names[1]+' e 2o Valor = '+ListaLimpeza.ValueFromIndex[1]);
```

This works, but it's not good for visuals, since I can't code the before string (for ex `' .'`) like that (which is very visual for the SPACE character), only like (`" .`) so that the `=` works to assign a name and value in the TStringList.

Comment: Your posting would be MUCH easier to read if you used the standard delimiter and quote characters in your example.  Does your sample code work if you use them?  I suspect that you are failing to use these characters properly in your DelimitedText assignment. But I gave up trying to untangle your example when I encountered the strange choice of characters.  Suggestion: you'll get better responses on SA if you stick to the standard defaults rather than | and !, unless you can't make the problem happen with the standards. Perhaps someone else here will have the brains and guts to dig into yours.

Comment: I've made some edits, I believe it's more understandable now. Could you check please.

Comment: Have you considered separating how you *edit* the list from how you *store* it? For editing, try a two-column grid so you don't need to worry about quoting or delimiting. Then, store the strings however you want. Don't worry about storing them in a format that's easy for you to read; just make sure it can be loaded unambiguously by your program.

Comment: If your code doesn't do what you expect, you need to debug it. Use the debugger that comes with Delphi.

Comment: I believe the problem is with StringReplace. Do you know of it not respecting whitespaces?

Comment: This would be so much easier if you used something like JSON. You are trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit, because it changed the entire meaning and intent of the question. Once a question has received an answer, you can't change the whole question, because it invalidates the answer(s) you've already received. If you now have a question about string replacements, that should be posted as a new, separate question. You can link back to this one from there for context and history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Names` and `Values` by default have to be separated by `=`, in the style of Windows INI files. <strike>There's no way AFAICT to change that separator.</strike> As @SirRufo indicates in the comment (and which I had never noticed), you can change that using the `TStringList.NameValueSeparator` property.

This will give you an idea of what Delphi thinks is in your `TStringList`, which is not what you think it is:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SL: TStringList;
  Temp: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  SL.Delimiter := '|';
  SL.QuoteChar := '"';
  SL.StrictDelimiter := True;
  SL.DelimitedText := 'O=0 | ! .!=!.!';
  Temp := 'Count: ' + IntToStr(SL.Count) + #13;
  for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    Temp := Temp + Format('Name: %s Value: %s'#13, 
              [SL.Names[i], SL.ValueFromIndex[i]]);
  ShowMessage(Temp);
end;
```

This produces this output:

[image: Sample ShowMessage output from above code]

`TStringList` Names/Values probably isn't going to do what you need. It's not clear what your actual goal is, but it appears that a simple text file with a simple list of `text|replacement` and plain parsing of that file would work, and you can easily use `TStringList` to read/write from that file, but I don't see any way to do the parsing easily except to do it yourself. You could use an array to store the pairs when you parse them:

```
type
  TReplacePair = record
    TextValue: string;
    ReplaceValue: string;
  end;

  TReplacePairs = array of TReplacePair;

function GetReplacementPairs: TReplacePairs;
var
  ConfigInfo: TStringList;
  i, Split: Integer;
begin
  ConfigInfo := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ConfigInfo.LoadFromFile('ReplacementPairs.txt');
    SetLength(Result, ConfigInfo.Count);
    for i := 0 to ConfigInfo.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Split := Pos('|`, ConfigInfo[i];
      Result[i].TextValue := Copy(ConfigInfo[i], 1, Split - 1);
      Result[i].ReplaceValue := Copy(ConfigInfo[i], Split + 1, MaxInt);
    end;
  finally
    ConfigInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can then populate whatever controls you need to edit/add/delete the replacement pairs, and just reverse the read operation to write them back out to save.

Comment: yes, I understand. I believe I'm gonna need to go to another approach, I'm thinking in using: `'|O|==|0| ,       | .|==|.| , ...'` in a string and then using code so to dismantle it so that the proper replacements are identified. Is there any easier solution which would give me a visual code like that?

Comment: I added a suggestion for a solution, but `TStringList`s built-in functionality isn't going to help. You could always create your own descendant that would do this for you, though.

Comment: The NameValueSeparator char can changed by using the TStrings.NameValueSeparator property http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStrings.NameValueSeparator

Comment: @SirRufo: Thanks man, didn't know of the property and it is gonna make my life a lot easier :)

Comment: @SirRufo: I'd never noticed that property either (I apparently didn't need it). Thanks. I updated my answer (with proper credit, of course).