# StringReplace not working as expected

Tags: string, delphi, replace

This is a new question of this topic:

[How do I store and load a list of key-value pairs in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908741/how-do-i-store-and-load-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-in-a-string)

I have come to the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.BotaoLimpaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListaSubstituicoes, Atual: String;
  ListaLimpeza, Pares: TStringList;
  i: Integer; //('O' , ' .' , '.' , '/' , '-');

begin
  ListaSubstituicoes := '|O| = |0| , | .| = |.| , . , / , -';

  TextoCompleto := Trim(EditTexto.Text);
  ListaLimpeza := TStringList.Create;
  Pares := TStringList.Create;

  ExtractStrings([','],[], PChar(ListaSubstituicoes), ListaLimpeza);
  for i := 0 to (ListaLimpeza.Count - 1) do
  begin
    Atual := ListaLimpeza[i];
    Atual := Trim(Atual);
    if Pos('=', Atual) = 0 then
    begin
      TextoCompleto := 
        StringReplace(TextoCompleto, Atual, '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
      Continue;
    end;

    Pares.Clear;
    ExtractStrings(['='],[], PChar(Atual), Pares);
    Pares.Text := 
      StringReplace(Pares.Text, '|', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    //Pares[1] := StringReplace(Pares[1], '|', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    TextoCompleto := 
      StringReplace(TextoCompleto, Pares[0], Pares[1], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  end;
```

it's driving me crazy tho. When I apply it to the following:

75691 .30698 02053447138 05764.100011 5 572500000382o0

it simple does not work! It doesn't remove the ' .306' white space and it doesn't replaces the o with 0 in the end of the statement. Why is that? I believe it has to do with StringReplace not working correctly, probably it's not respecting the ' ' whitespaces, any clues?

Pares[0] is correctly getting the 'O' value and Pares[1] is correctly getting '0'. I've checked with trace into. But strangely,  `TextoCompleto := StringReplace(TextoCompleto, Pares[0], Pares[1], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);` is not producing the desired result of replacing `572500000382o0` with `57250000038200`

Comment: Far too much code here. Boil it down to a single call to `StringReplace`. Use literals for the two string parameters.

Comment: Have you used the debugger yet? That's how everyone else investigates problems like this. Confirm that you're passing the right values to the function you accuse of misbehaving. Use the watch window and the tooltip expression evaluator.

Comment: I did that. That's exactly how I've come to the conclusion that it's a problem with StringReplace.

Comment: If you think it's a problem with `StringReplace` then do as I said and supply a single line of code that produces erroneous answer. Even better, wrap it in a minimal console program so that we can just cut and paste and run. You can demonstrate the supposed bug with <10 lines of code and a complete program. Please do it.

Comment: I've found and fixed the problem. Will post it in an answer to my own question, just waiting the 8 hours site rule.

Comment: Your update is no good. Why can't you do what I asked? I don't actually care about this problem. What I care about is teaching you how to solve problems. And cutting a problem down to a minimal reproduction is bug hunting 101.

Comment: I don't understand your rudeness, as I've said i've used debbuging and that's how I've found where the problem is. But with so many strings and replacements it was not easy to find that it was a problem with whitespaces.

Comment: About literals I don't have much knowledge in that, if you could give me a code example, i've searched google but didn't get the concept.

Comment: A literal is when you get rid of the variables and the function calls and write a value *literally* into your code instead of calculating it from other values. So, you're saying that `StringReplace('75691 .30698 02053447138 05764.100011 5 572500000382o0', 'O', '0', [rfReplaceAl, rfIgnoreCase])` returns a string that still contains the letter *o*? Run that exact code and confirm that `StringReplace` behaves the way you accuse it of. If it doesn't, then investigate something else. This is called *debugging*.

Comment: That's some evil code.

Comment: "But with so many strings and replacements it was not easy to find that it was a problem with whitespaces." Exactly my point. If you had turned it into a single line of code with literals it would have been easy to see what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the desired result, as far as I could follow ...

```
const
  ListaSubstituicoes = 'O=0, .=.';
var
  ListaLimpeza: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  TextoCompleto:String;
begin

      TextoCompleto := Trim(EditTexto.Text);
      ListaLimpeza := TStringList.Create;
      try
      ExtractStrings([','],[], PChar(ListaSubstituicoes), ListaLimpeza);
      for i := 0 to (ListaLimpeza.Count - 1) do
        begin
            TextoCompleto := StringReplace(TextoCompleto, ListaLimpeza.Names[i], ListaLimpeza.ValueFromIndex[i], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
        end;
      Caption := TextoCompleto; // test
      finally
         ListaLimpeza.Free;
      end;
end;
```

referring to your comment and link, you are pobably looking for something like this, of course `"` could be replaced by e.g. `|`

```
const
  ListaSubstituicoes = '"O"="0"," ."="."';
var
  ListaLimpeza: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  TextoCompleto:String;
begin
      TextoCompleto := Trim(EditTexto.Text);
      ListaLimpeza := TStringList.Create;
      try
      ExtractStrings([','],[], PChar(StringReplace(ListaSubstituicoes,'"','',[rfReplaceAll])), ListaLimpeza);
      for i := 0 to (ListaLimpeza.Count - 1) do
        begin
            TextoCompleto := StringReplace(TextoCompleto, ListaLimpeza.Names[i], ListaLimpeza.ValueFromIndex[i], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
        end;
     Caption := TextoCompleto;
      finally
         ListaLimpeza.Free;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: bummi, i've updated the OP with a link so you can follow the background of it.

Comment: i'm trying it right now, problem is, what if I have `ListaSubstituicoes = '"O" = "0" , " ."="."';` ie. whitespaces in the constant.

Comment: to remove all whitespaces if desired you could use  ListaSubstituicoes = '"O"="0"," "=""';

Comment: yes, manually yes, but I want automatically =D so the visual of the list is easier to understand (I preffer `'|O| = |0| , | .| = |.| , . , / , -'` to `'"O"="0"," "=""'`). But I have good news, I've found and fixed the problem, i'm gonna post it in an answer to my own question, just can't do that right now because must wait 8 hours as of site rules. It was a matter of Trim really!

Comment: as i mentioned replacing `"` with `|` is not a problem I don't understand what the part `, . , / , -'` shall do.

Comment: it doesn't have a reason to be written like that other than making it visually easier to read / edit. As of the function of `, . , / , -` the program is designed to clean strings. Those are 3 characters the program must remove if exist-ant. I could write it like `|.| = ||` but the program is smart enough so that I can write just `.`

Answer (score 0):

Crap, the only thing that was making the code not work was a lack of trim.

```
StringReplace( -> Trim <- (Pares.Text), '|', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

But I believe working with `Pares.Text` like that is not good coding, so I've replaced it with:

```
ExtractStrings(['='],[], PChar(Atual), Pares);
Pares[0] := StringReplace(Trim(Pares[0]), '|', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Pares[1] := StringReplace(Trim(Pares[1]), '|', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Shame that you did not heed my advice. That would have made the question simple. And simple for you too. Why come here for help if you don't heed the advice?

Comment: Man, if you want to say something just say it please. Do you want me to salute you, something like that? What is this advice that you so much speaks?

Comment: The comments to the question that I added. If you had boiled this down to one line, it would have been easy to understand.

Comment: Boil what to one line, the problem?

Comment: Exactly. You can illustrate the issue with a single line of code. The call to `StringReplace`. Instead of passing variables, pass string literals. So, a string literal is something like this `'foo'`. Replace the variables that you pass as parameters with string literals containing the same value as your variables. As @Rob says in his comment, this is standard debugging.

Comment: It works greatly after I've fixed the Trim issue. If you want to give me a code example of the same program with less lines of code as you say I would happily appreciate it.

Comment: Rob's comment to the question shows you how to do it. Like I said, I don't really care about the specifics of this particular problem. I'm trying to get across the techniques of problem solving.